# Update PHP installation on my Mac, not change PATH

Tags: php, macos, osx-elcapitan

IMHO installing a second PHP installation on `Mac OS El Captain` and then changing the `PATH variable` to point at the new installation is complete BS.
 That is not the way OS should work and it's making me super annoyed that Apple expects us to do like that.

I want to do a proper installation of the latest PHP version and thus removing the old one.

Is this even possible?
 And if yes, how?

Thank you kindly for all help.

Comment: Don't use *UPDATE* in a title, the edit history shows people how and when a question is updated - it's just noise. Might as well edit out the ranting in your question while you are at it. I don't use Apple, so you may be right, but it's not relevant to your question and is just noise that's frowned upon here.

Comment: Is it the php just in terminal you are having issues with? Or php for the web side of it?

Comment: Both. I want to update the installation of PHP, I don't want two different PHP versions installed in the OS since that seems extremely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the question.

OS X comes by default with a PHP 5.5 installation (/usr/bin/php). Installing a newer version of PHP on OS X (e.g. Homebrew) will not replace this default 5.5 installation but will instead place a new PHP version in another location. It will link binaries in /usr/local/bin. To use the new PHP version you have to make sure /usr/local/bin comes *before* /usr/bin in your PATH variable.

The original poster does not want to update his PATH variable in this way and is asking for a way to update the original 5.5 installation from Apple instead of installing a new one next to it and perform some PATH variable magic.